# Spring - How to initialize map by annotations only

Tags: java, spring

Is it possible to initialize Map by using only annotations? I want to have my package and its sub-packages independent, so I don't want to define anything in the context.xml.

Comment: And how do you want to specify the map content?

Comment: You can `@Autowire` the `Map`, and in a `@Configuration` class declare a `@Bean` method returning the `Map` of your choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Configuration did the job. This is the configuration class

```
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
public class Configuration {

    @Autowired
    private ImportHandler monographImportHandler;

    @Autowired
    private ImportHandler periodicalImportHandler;

    @Bean(name = "importHandlerCatalog")
    @Scope("prototype")
    public Map<MetsFileType, ImportHandler> sipPackageProcessorCatalog() {
        Map<MetsFileType, ImportHandler> catalog = new HashMap<>();
        catalog.put(MetsFileType.MONOGRAPH, monographImportHandler);
        catalog.put(MetsFileType.PERIODICAL, periodicalImportHandler);
        return catalog;
    }

}
```

And this is how I access it:

```
@Resource(name = "importHandlerCatalog")
public Map<MetsFileType, ImportHandler> importHandlerCatalog;
```